# Selectize.js - stop event item_add

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I am using [selectize](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md) and I have set it up so that a user can select only one from an array of options, and if he wants to, he can make a new input as well. I would like to make it so, that if the user selects one of the options, the input item gets a class, which would style it, as the selectize styles the selected items when multiple options are enabled.

[image]

But if the user enters it's own input, the input would get no style, so there would be difference in entered input and selected input. But I am not sure how to do that?

This is my script:

```
$('#engagement_question').selectize({
    persist: false,
    maxItems: 1,
    options: items,
    labelField: "item",
    valueField: "item",
    sortField: 'item',
    searchField: 'item',
    create: true,
    render: {
      option_create: function(data, escape) {
        return '<div class="create">Nytt inlegg<strong> ' + escape(data.input) + '</strong>&hellip;</div>';
      }
    },
});
```

I have tried with using events api, but with no luck:

```
var addItemClass = function() {
    console.log('entered');
    $('.item').addClass( "item-background" );
};

var removeItemClass = function() {
    console.log('entered');
    $('.item').removeClass( "item-background" );
};

var selectize = $select[0].selectize;
selectize.on('item_add', addItemClass);
selectize.on('option_add', removeItemClass);
```

The idea was to add a class that would give a background to an input if it was selected from the options and remove it if it was typed new. But when it enters function `removeItemClass`, it immedialy enters the `addItemClass` function too.
How can I stop that?

**Update**

In the end I used this to make it work the way I wanted it:

```
onChange: function(value) {
      var unique = true;

      for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if(items[i].item == value) {
          unique = false;
          break;
        }
      }

      if(value.length > 0 && unique) {
        $question.next('.selectize-control').find('.selectize-input').addClass('user-created');
      }
    },
```

Comment: May it helps [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/g18sdxr5/#&togetherjs=xGJgD95R7k)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`removeItemClass` is internally fired from `selectize.js`. Here we checked if the last `.item text` not matches in existing elements in`items array` than the `background-image` which is a `gradient` is set to `none` and our `item-background` Class is applied

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/g18sdxr5/#&togetherjs=xGJgD95R7k)

**JS:**

```
 var items = [
        { id: 1, item: 'Spectrometer' },
        { id: 2, item: 'Star Chart' },
        { id: 3, item: 'Electrical Tape' }
        ];

            var $select = $('#engagement_question').selectize({
                persist: false,
                maxItems: 3,
                options: items,
                labelField: "item",
                valueField: "item",
                sortField: 'item',
                searchField: 'item',
                create: true,
                render: {
                    option_create: function (data, escape) {
                        return '<div class="create">Nytt inlegg<strong> ' + escape(data.input) + '</strong>&hellip;</div>';
                    }
                },
            });
            var addItemClass = function () {
                console.log('entered1');
                var input = $.map(items, function (element, index) {
                    if (element.item == $('.item:last').text())
                        return element;
                    else
                        return null;
                });
                if (input.length == 0)
                {
                    $('.item:last').css('background-image', 'none');
                }
                $('.item:last').addClass("item-background");

            };

            var removeItemClass = function () {
                console.log('entered2');
                $('.item:last').removeClass("item-background");
                //$('.item').css('background-image', 'none');
            };

            var selectize = $select[0].selectize;
            selectize.on('item_add', addItemClass);
            selectize.on('option_add', removeItemClass);
```

**CSS**

```
.item-background {
            background-color:#000!important;
        }
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="engagement_question" multiple>

</select>
```

Comment: Thank you alot for your help, I have ended up with the same approach you suggest.

Comment: @RonyLoud, How to keep a value without adding new option? Please give an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66532247/how-to-keep-a-typed-value-without-adding-new-item-in-selectize). Thank you.