# How to keep a typed value without adding new item in selectize?

Tags: jquery, selectize.js

I want to keep a typed value manually without creating a new item in selectize element.

Ideally, the typed value should be submitted and also it can be selectable in a form.

[image]

My selectize options are the following.

```
const $selected_location = $('.select-beast select[name="location"]').selectize({
    options: [{
        value: '',
        text: 'Select location...'
    },
    {
        value: 'ms_teams',
        text: 'Microsoft Teams'
    }],
    placeholder: 'Select location...',
    allowEmptyOption: true,
    create: function (input) {
        return {};
    },
    createOnBlur: true
});
```

The selectize should not add typed value but keep the value.

[image]

Comment: If I am getting your context right than [this](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/ph3k6q4z/#&togetherjs=QppeQAoaQt) may help

Comment: @RonyLoud No, it should not remove the typed value even if it lost focus.